# NSTextView links stay "baked" even when text is refreshed

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

It seems that after I change text string in a `NSTextView` the text, the new text will still be *hyperlinked* and point to the previous text.

Here's the code bit:

```
    self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = true
    self.textView.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = true

    self.textView.string = "http://www.google.com"
    self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil) // required to get the link working

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        // This will appear as link to google (NOT GOOD)
        self.textView.string = "This is a test." 
        self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil) // This doesn't help 
    }
```

To make things easier I've put up a GitHub project so you can witness this miracle easily: https://github.com/switchawk/NSTextViewLinks

**UPDATE**

1. The idea is for the textview string to accommodate mixed content of text and links and text and be updated correctly.
2. The text needs to assigned programmatically

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to do another push to GitHub because the current version on GitHub doesn't have any of the code you are referring to.

Comment: You're right. Pushed.

Comment: When I run the code and replace the string with valid web address and keep the `self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)` active in the `DispatchQueue` it works correctly.

Comment: So the question remains why it keeps linking when showing a non-web address.

Comment: First, understand that it's perfectly sane to have text that's not in the form of a URL be a link. Most links on this very page are that way. Second, `checkTextInDocument()` is finding URLs in the text and applying `NSLinkAttributeName` to that stretch of text, but it would be wrong of it to strip that attribute from non-URL text. Third, when you just assign a new string, it uses the attributes of the first character of the previous text as the attributes of the new text. Assigning a new **attributed** string doesn't attempt to copy existing attributes because it doesn't need to.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as expected:

```
textView.textStorage!.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: ...))
textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but on iOS I had the same issue and it helped to turn data detectors off and on again after setting the new string.

So I assume on MacOS:

```
self.textView.string = "This is a test."
self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = false
self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = true
```

Comment: You can also try toggling `isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled` if nobody has better ideas

Answer (score 0):

The real question is how are you planing to set the `textView.string`? You could achieve the result you want in one of these ways.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.textView.string = "This is a test!"
        if (self.textView.string?.hasPrefix("http:"))! {
            self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)

        } else {
            self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = false
            self.textView.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = false
            self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)
            let currentText = self.textView.string
            self.textView.string = ""
            self.textView.string = currentText

        }
    }
}
```

Even if you just run this code. You remove all the text and type an non-linkable text in the box it will not show up as link.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = true
    self.textView.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = true

    self.textView.string = "http://www.google.com"
    self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)
    print(self.textView.string!)


}
```

If you run this code you get the same effect as if you removed all the text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = true
    self.textView.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = true

    self.textView.string = "http://www.google.com"
    self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)
    print(self.textView.string!)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.textView.string = ""
        self.textView.string = "This is a test!"
    }


}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment and your answer the working code would look like this.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textView.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = true
        self.textView.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = true
        self.textView.string = "http://www.google.com"
        self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
             self.textView.textStorage!.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "This is a test! http://www.espn.com"))
             self.textView.checkTextInDocument(nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: The idea is placing random text and links and having the desired result. If it's a link, it'll be detected, if it's just text it won't. It can also be mixed text and links.

Comment: Another clarification: The text needs to be assigned programmatically